# How do I navigate to a page that has a constructor parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter stateful page. Here it is:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {

  static const String id = 'TestPage';


  final String testString;

  TestPage(this.testString);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(child: Text('Hello ${widget.testString}'))
    );
  }
}
```

The page has a constructor that takes in a string as a default value.

```
 final String testString;
```

From another page, I make a call to that page. I want to open it and give it or pass to it a String value:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, TestPage(myString));
```

However, it is telling me:

that the argument type 'TestPage' cannot be assigned to the parameter type String.

What am I doing wrong? Is this not the correct way to instantiate this class and make it appear?

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with the constructor taking a parameter.  You're passing a `TestPage` object, but [`Navigator.pushNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html) expects a `String`.

Comment: OK.. thanks, and so which method do I use or should I use to get to my page? Bearing in mind that the class takes in parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this,

```
Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => TestPage(testString: 'Hello',), ));
```